# The value of the fifteenth derivative of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^3 2^{-n} x^n$ at $x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

I know how to find the value of the $n$th derivative of a series using the Maclaurin formula. I want to find the value of the $15$th derivative of a series, however, I do not know what to do when the series begins at $1$ instead of $0$. My solution involved just adding one to the $n$ of the series. But unfortunately this gives me a $x^{n+1}$ term. For example when starting with the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^32^{-n}x^n$$ I would turn it into $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)^3 2^{-n-1} x^{n+1}.$$
Is this possible? If I do this I get the answer $16^3 \times 15!/2^{16}$. I assume because $x=0$ the $x^{n+1}$ would not be a problem but unfortunately the Maclaurin formula has a $x^n$ in it and not a $x^{n+1}$.